# Logical error while passing data from service.ts to component.ts in Angular

Tags: angular, service

I'm working on a bookstore project.
I have an auth.service.ts file and register component.
What I'm trying to do is to call register() located in service from component file and then I want to return the error message back to the component through "errMsg".
Look at the service file below--

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  isLoading: boolean = false;
  
  errMsg: string = '';
  
  // REGISTER
  register(form: RegisterForm) {
    const auth = getAuth();

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, form.email, form.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log(userCredential);
        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
        
        this.errMsg = errorMessage;
        
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });

      return this.errMsg
  }
}
```

register.component.ts--

```
export class RegisterComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

  }
  form: RegisterForm = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirm_password: ''
  }
  
  passwordMatched: boolean = true;
  
  errMsg: string = '';
  isLoading: boolean = false;

  submit() {
    
    if(this.isLoading) {return;}

    this.isLoading = true;
    
    if(this.form.password != this.form.confirm_password) {
      this.passwordMatched = false;
      this.isLoading = false 
      return;
    }

    this.errMsg = this.authService.register(this.form);
    console.log(this.errMsg);
    
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

This errMsg is used in template as--

```
<div *ngIf=" errMsg != '' ">
      {{errMsg}}
</div>
```

So, problem is that when the error is returned by service, it is somehow not stored in the "errMsg" variable in the component file only the first time I press submit. The second time I press submit, the error is displayed properly. I think there's some asynchornous process going on somehow but I dont know how.

I'm expecting that if error is received, it should instantly be displayed on template.

Comment: Try this: `async register(form: RegisterForm): Promise<string>` in the service. And in the component `async submit()` and then `await this.errMsg = this.authService.register(this.form);`

Comment: Your code is asynchronous. You have to return a promise or an observable with the error. In the component, you can `await` or `subscribe` to the message.

Comment: @Benny while returning a promise, I'm getting error "Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'". Then I set errMsg: any = ''; . Now, how do I access the message in template. It's displaying "object:Promise" in the template.

Comment: @HarshSonar Before your register function get completed you return errMsg from function.

Comment: I missed one more thing: `this.authService.register(this.form).then(err => { this.errMsg = err; console.log(this.errMsg); this.isLoading = false; })`

Comment: @Benny it's not working. It's giving me same problem. It's still asynchronous.